# MySQL user with restricted privilege on DB

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

How can I create a MySQL user and provide only access to a particular table ?
Can I hide rest of the DB from that user ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL user access - table specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300525/mysql-user-access-table-specific)

Comment: That FAQ says, "If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!"

Unfortunately, it seems like @hsz and @stefgosselin didn't understand the implied part of that text, in that people will freely provide the answers first.  Kudos to @tutor, who now gets an upvote for being helpful and non-snooty.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, read all the details regarding [MySQL GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) privileges to users.

Comment: We can do it by using the Mysql yog's Tools->userManager->Manage Privileges option, Finlay Don't forget to give a flush privileges;

Comment: if you don;t accept any answers, then nobody will answer you anymore