# Trigger to prevent delete on table

Tags: mysql

How can I prevent deletion of any row for specific tables in MySQL 5.1?

I don't need any where criteria, I simply do not want any row in these tables to be deleted.

Must be done on the MySQL level, as we also use bought software that accepts deletion. We use MySQL 5.1.66-cll

I have tried to tweak different triggers out there for this, but i am not able to succeed.

Comment: Please post what you've tried already

Comment: limit the privilege of user for delete action

Comment: but if i limit the user priviledge, that will apply to all tables, right? There are about 70 tables, and I need to prevent deletion from about 6 of these

Comment: I have tried different things I have found on internet, but I don't seem to succeed. One that I still have in the workbench is: CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE DELETE ON pr_ah
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      IF (products_ID >0) THEN
           SELECT 1/0 FROM pr_ah LIMIT 1
      END IF
END

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300525/mysql-user-access-table-specific

Comment: My problem is that most seem to need some criteria (id department = 10, or if there is only one row in the table etc.) I just want to prevent deletion from specific tables for every single row there is inside.

Comment: I am not able to do anything with the user grant at the moment. I can probably get these from my web host though. But then I have to specify all the 50-60 tables where records CAN be deleted, right?

Comment: REVOKE DELETE ON your_tables TO user@host http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-revoke.aspx

Comment: not able to GRANT anything, apparently :(

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned in the comments, the proper way to do this is usually via table level grants.

However, it can be accomplished with a trigger as you requested.

One way to do this is to use a "before delete" trigger, and execute a simple SQL statement that will always cause an error. For example, you can call a non-existent stored procedure like "do_not_delete".

Try something like this:

```
delimiter $$

drop trigger if exists tr_your_table_no_deletes $$

create trigger tr_your_table_no_deletes before delete on your_table for each row begin
  call do_not_delete();
end $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: how do i make the function do_not_delete()? This seems like a really simple and elegant solution, but I don't really know what it's calling.

Comment: I am not able to grant anything, the users are made through cpanel. I have been able to make a user that does not have permission to delete or drop, that will be implemented tomorrow, but the problem is that the user really needs to delete from certain tables (the joint in a many-to-many-relationship) now and then (if double up, things stop functioning). I will check with the web hotel tomorrow about GRANT privileges, but is there really no simple way to hinder the deletion of records in general from a specific table?

Comment: You do not need to create a `do_not_delete` function. The point of that solution is to call a stored procedure that *does not exist*. Then the delete fails with an error like this: `mysql> delete from your_table where name = 'bob';
ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE DO_NOT_DELETE does not exist`, which is what you want I think.